# Error using transferspreadsheet acimport in VBA with a worksheet that has pound (#) signs in the name

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to transfer data from excel to an Access table using the transferspreadsheet function with the acimport option but am getting an error. The worksheet that I'm importing has pound signs in the name (this is non-negotiable). I know that I can open the file via excel object, but don't want to go that route.

Using the following code:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "tTest", "C:\Users\tnh3spb\Desktop\test.xlsx", True, "#test#!"
```

or likewise

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "tTest", "C:\Users\tnh3spb\Desktop\test.xlsx", True, "" & Chr(35) & "test" & Chr(35) & "!"
```

gives me the same error where the worksheet cannot be found and the pound signs have been changed to periods (.)
[VBA Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcZLI.png)

Comment: A range address should follow the exclamation mark.  If you want to import the used range of the worksheet and a specific range then you should remove the exclamation mark.

Comment: Does not matter if i specify a range or not, the problem lies with the pound/hashtag symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've discovered the solution to this. I needed to use a STRING data type declaration while also surrounding the name of the tab in single quotes:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "tTest", "C:\Users\tnh3spb\Desktop\test.xlsx", True, "'#test#$'"
```